# sequence $c_n$ with $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f_n(x)|>\frac{c_n}{n}\})<2^{-n}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be Borel-measurable functions. Show that there exists a sequence $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in(0,\infty)$ with $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f_n(x)|>\frac{c_n}{n}\})<2^{-n}$
As a hint I got: You can use that for a Borel measurable function $f$, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>k\})=0$.
I started with 
$\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f_n(x)|>\frac{c_n}{n}\})=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{\{x\in[0,1]:|f_n(x)|>\frac{c_n}{n}\}}$ but I dont know how to go on.

Comment: Start with the hint. Applythe definition of limit

Comment: For $\varepsilon=2^{-n}$ there exists $\n_0 \in \mathbb N$ with $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f_n(x)|>n\})<2^{-k}$ Is this correct? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: I mean, that really isn't the correct formulation for the definition of the limit. You should probably explicitly say if you've made any other attempts with David's hint.

Comment: if i apply the definition of $\lim$ I get for every $\epsilon>$ there exists $k_0\in\mathbb N$ so that $\lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|>k\})<\epsilon$ for all $k\geq k_0$